# R-Using a list of Indices to calculate the mean of a group of values in several columns of a data frame

Tags: r, foreach, dataframe, data.table, mean

i have a list of indices that i want to use to calculate a mean of a fix number of rows starting from my index. Ideally, i would find a way to do this for several columns at the same time.

My list of indices looks something like this:

```
a = seq(1,100,10)
```

My data frame is similar to:

```
df<-data.frame(A= 0:10, b=10:20, c = 20:30, d=40:50, e = seq(0,100,10))
    A  b  c  d   e
1   0 10 20 40   0
2   1 11 21 41  10
3   2 12 22 42  20
4   3 13 23 43  30
5   4 14 24 44  40
6   5 15 25 45  50  etc...
```

What i would like would be a way, to get means out of this data frame, for all columns in a manner like:

```
colnames = c("A", "b", "c")

    means(df[(a-4):(a), colnames])
```

Now obviously that doesn't work, but i hope it illustrates my idea. I want a mean of the last 5 entrys counting backwards from `a`.

Now i have tried with the `foreach` package (probably wrongly so) and if i use

```
library(foreach)
test <- foreach(i = a) %do% mean(df[(i-4):(i),"A"])
```

i get a working result, which is a list with the means i want, but only for column "A".
If i instead use

```
test <- foreach(i = a, j = colnames) %do% mean(df[(i-4):(i),j])
```

i somehow only get one value per column.

I have looked into solutions with `sapply and tapply` but i am either too stupid to understand how to use those iteratively for parts of a column or they are just not made for that.

Lastly people regularly come up with `data.table`, but i quite honestly have no idea how the syntax works in this case. I know that

```
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[,mean(A[(a-4):(a)])]
```

returns

```
numerical expression has 10 elements: only the first used
```

which was the problem in the first place with `mean`. If i try to use my colnames parameter, it gets even worse

```
DT[,mean(colnames[(a-4):(a)]), with = FALSE]
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I am sorry if I am posting an obvious question, but hours of search here and elsewhere on the internet and in R reference documents and the documentation have left me with the feeling that this is not that easy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

P.S.: Should it help in any way, `a` is derived from evaluating other parts of the dataframe like `a = which(thetruth & nothingbut)` and could if necessary also be used as logical. I just think i have more overview with this construction.

**Update**

I wanted a subset of data in both column as in several rows defined by a list.
The solution

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(a, function(x) colMeans(DT[(x-4):x,colNames], na.rm=T)))
```

works as well as

```
rbindlist(lapply(a, function(x) DT[(x-4):x, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = colnames]))
```

If there is a date column with class `POSIXct` the function `colMeans` cannot process it, which means you either convert your date into numeric, or use the `data.table` solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `colMeans` called on a subset of `DT`. You an use `lapply` to call it on each value in `a`, and then `do.call` with `rbind` to build a matrix where the rows are the column means for the corresponding value in `a`:

```
DT <- data.frame(A= 0:10, b=10:20, c = 20:30, d=40:50, e = seq(0,100,10))
a <- 5:7
colNames <- c("A", "b", "c")
do.call(rbind, lapply(a, function(x) colMeans(DT[(x-4):x,colNames], na.rm=T)))
#      A  b  c
# [1,] 2 12 22
# [2,] 3 13 23
# [3,] 4 14 24
```

Comment: the `data.table` version of this is: `rbindlist(lapply(a, function(x) DT[(x-4):x, lapply(.SD, mean)]))`

Comment: @DL42.5 I added the column names and an `na.rm=T` option (though we don't need it in this simple example). My code doesn't produce your `'x' must be numeric` issue -- can you double check your `a` vector?

Comment: The `do.call` described above just returns `'x' must be numeric` although `class(a) = "integer"`. Not really any idea where to start the troubleshooting there. The `data.table` Version works with `rbindlist(lapply(a, function(x) DT[(x-4):x, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = colnames]))`  Also if you could point me where to add in this construct `na.rm` that would be very nice.

Comment: @josilber i tried on my real data both with the `a` specified here and as well with the one i want to use and both times get `Error in colMeans(DT[(x - 1):x, ]) : 'x' must be numeric` Possibly the problem is that my data is not all integers and colmeans doesn't replace non-integers with `NA`. One of the reasons i want to be able to specifiy the columns first.

Comment: OK, try with the updated code, which does specify the columns. Yeah, it sounds like some of your columns were not numbers.

Comment: Yes that works now. Although my time column with `class "POSIXct"` seems to be able to be handled only by the `data.table` solution. But i did not specify that in my question, i will update it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Not super clear what you want, but it sounds like you want a running mean:

```
library(caTools)

DT[, lapply(.SD, function(col) runmean(col, 5, align = 'right')),
     .SDcols = c("A", "b", "c")]
#      A    b    c
# 1: 0.0 10.0 20.0
# 2: 0.5 10.5 20.5
# 3: 1.0 11.0 21.0
# 4: 1.5 11.5 21.5
# 5: 2.0 12.0 22.0
# 6: 3.0 13.0 23.0
# 7: 4.0 14.0 24.0
# 8: 5.0 15.0 25.0
# 9: 6.0 16.0 26.0
#10: 7.0 17.0 27.0
#11: 8.0 18.0 28.0
```